# NameError: uninitialized constant on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my UserTrainingController

```
  def create
   @user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource::Create.call(user_training_resource_params)
   respond_with(@user_training_resource)
 end
```

Then in Operations > Training Resource > Create

```
class UserTrainingResource
 class Create < Operation

   def call(params)
     user_training_resource = UserTrainingResource.new(params)
     ResourceMailer.requested(user_training_resource).deliver_later if user_training_resource.save
     user_training_resource
   end

 end
end
```

Then in my test I have

```
 require 'rails_helper'

 RSpec.describe UserTrainingResource::Create do

  let(:params) { attributes_for(:user_training_resource) }

  describe '#call' do
    it 'saves the request as pending' do
      ut = UserTrainingResource::Create.call(params)
      expect(ut.persisted?).to eq(true)
    end

    it 'queues a mailer' do
      expect(ResourceMailer).to send_mail(:requested)
      UserTrainingResource::Create.call(params)
    end
  end

end
```

The test gives me

> NameError: uninitialized constant UserTrainingResource::Create

I've no idea what the issue is. Is it not hitting my operations correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails expects that class to be defined in `app/models/user_training_resource/create.rb`, or you could add the dir to `config.autoload_paths`.

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/05/how-constant-lookup-happens-in-rails.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use `module`, like this:

```
module UserTrainingResource
  class Create < Operation
    ...
  end
end
```

Or the shorthand way, like this:

```
class UserTrainingResource::Create < Operation
end
```

Comment: Did not like the use of module but the shorthand worked

Answer (score 1):

The file structure must match the name of the class. Rename the directory to `app/models/user_training_resource/create.rb` or `lib/user_training_resource/create.rb`